# How complex is to solve subset-sum-problems using super increasing sequences with the following algorithm?

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, computational-complexity, cryptography

I'm writing about the Merkle-Hellman-Cryptosystem in my thesis, this uses subset-sum-problems (SSP) with super increasing sequences. The SSP is NP-complete, but the SSP consisting of super increasing sequences is easy to solve with the [following algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH2xP.png).

However my question is, what compexity the algorithm has? I found this algorithm on page 300 [here](https://doc.lagout.org/network/3_Cryptography/CRC%20Press%20-%20Handbook%20of%20applied%20Cryptography.pdf) but there is no specification (like `O(n^3)`) or something, just *Algorithm 8.35 efficiently solves the subset sum problem for superincreasing sequences.*. Do any of you know of a source where this is addressed? I need **a source for my thesis**, if it's possible...

Thanks

Comment: When you try to figure out the time complexity yourself, where do you get stuck?

Comment: @MishaLavrov I could calculate it roughly, but I'd like to back it up with an "official" source for my thesis.

Comment: what level is your thesis? Bachelor's? Master's? PhD?

Comment: @kodlu it's Bachelor.

Comment: edit your question sharing how you computed it roughly, after all this is central to your thesis. then maybe people can point out how to go to o(n^3) from there.